# Include carriage returns when calculating substring

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have some data which is stored in a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column that contains the control characters CR & LF (CHAR(10) & CHAR(13)).

I have some start and end position numbers that I need to use to extract a substring from the text - but when I use SUBSTRING these control characters are ignored, which results in the substring being extracted incorrectly.

I wrote a query using a CTE that replaced all instances of CRLF with another character (¬¬) and then the substring works correctly - however I need to retain the CRLFs in the text as they are used for display purposes.

Can anyone think of a way I can get the SUBSTRING function to include the control characters when it is calculating which part of the string to extract?

Comment: Can you show us your non-working code that uses `SUBSTRING`?

Comment: I think, more correctly, that the offsets you're trying to use have been calculated ignoring CRLF, rather than SUBSTRING doing things wrong - where are your SUBSTRING offset and length numbers coming from, and can they be corrected?

Comment: Yes actually on further investigation I think you're right Damien - it looks like the tool that calculated the offsets has counted carriage returns incorrectly.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server version of `substring` treats CRLF like other characters.  For example:

```
select substring('123' + char(10) + char(13) + '678',1,3)
-->
123

select substring('123' + char(10) + char(13) + '678',4,2)
-->
\r\n

select substring('123' + char(10) + char(13) + '678',6,3)
-->
678
```

Check your code again, or post a more specific example of where `substring` does not work as expected.